# groovy @TupleConstructor includeFields vs includeProperties

Tags: groovy, transform, abstract-syntax-tree

In groovy's [`@TupleConstructor`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html#callSuper) annotation, what is the difference between the `includeFields` and `includeProperties`. Does properties include just the public setter/getter and fields includes privates? I couldn't find any documentation relating to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Groovy field is a public property without getters and setters:

```
@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor(includeFields=false) 
class Invoice {
  Integer serie, number // properties
  BigDecimal total // property
  public Integer type // this is a field
}


try {
  i = new Invoice(1, 2, 10.0, 10)
  assert false
} catch (e) {
  assert true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Is there documentation on this?

Comment: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy%2BBeans: "If the name [of the attribute] is declared with an access modifier (public, private or protected) then a field is generated".